# Visual Studio Code - Debugar pelo Chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, debug, visual-studio-code

Ola,

Estou tentando debugar meu codigo `angular` do `visual studio code` com a extensao `debbuger for chrome`, porem não entra no meu `breakpoint` nunca, que inclusive esta **cinza** e escrito **não verificado**.

Imagens:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nas exceptions ele entra, nos meus breakpoints nao.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, na tag `webRoot` colocar ao final `/main`, no meu caso...

`"webRoot" : "${workspaceFolder}/main"`

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção seria colocar um "console.log();" no seu código passando o parâmetro que deseja inspecionar.
Com isso utilizando o F12 do Chrome vc acessa a aba de console, e la está o item que você enviou dentro do "console.log();"